# Household 3 phase devices

Tags: power, power-transmission, current, ac

So, I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but have been working on modifying a lawn mower robot that has, for roughly 3 years now been stored under less than favorable conditions. As a result, the motor driver is broken, and I don't have the materials here to fix it, the main problem being a capacitor. Now, it's going to be a while before I can get a replacement part, but I still want to tinker, and since all motors run on a 3 phase current, I was wondering if there are some other household devices that use 3 phase motors. Fans maybe? A power drill? To put it simply, what could I cannibalize to get a 3 phase power supply? (Or DC to 3Ph or AC to 3Ph)

Comment: all motors do not run on 3-phase current, 480V motors do.  You can't get true 3-phase power from a USA mains panel.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear from the question; 3phase here refers to any alternating current whose 3 phases are 120 degrees out of synch, as that is how those motors operate, I wasn't specifically talking about the standardized 400 something volt outlet current that feeds into a typical fuse box. (In my country at least, austria, its called starkstrom here)

Comment: @MatNX that 120 degree sync makes the current higher voltage because the effective difference is higher. So if you take all the 3 phases then its the same thing as goes into your fusebox. In other case your looking at a phase converter